# Cookies-js doesn't work when setting up with domain option

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using [cookies-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js) npm module on the client side.

```
Cookies.set('key', 'value', { domain: 'www.example.com', secure: true });
```

I am using this method on my subdomain:

```
something.mydomain.com
```

and parameter I provided is `{domain: 'www.mydomain.com'}`

However, when I set domain option, this method no longer works and doesn't throw any error either.

```
Cookies.set('indicator', response, {domain: "www.mydomain.com", expires: Infinity});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused beacuse of `www` prefix in the string. By removing it it will set cookie and it will work.

**So basically use domain strings such as `.example.com`**

I also posted comment on the issue on GitHub for author to catch errors in the future rather than letting library fail silently.